# Adding $_SESSION to PHP script for HeaderName in apache

Tags: php, apache, apache2, session

So I have a login script that assigns a session to the user once he logs in. This script normally redirects to the index if the session DOES NOT exist, else it continues to another php script called login_successful.php

I added the session script to the HeaderName because I have a file directory that needs to be protected from people who are NOT logged in and I want to prevent direct URL access to the files in uploads directory. I don't want to list the directory using PHP for sheer simplicity. Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
AddType text/html .php
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php
HeaderName /header.php
```

Here is my header.php for Apache HeaderName:

```
<?php
session_start();
// IF USER NOT REMEMBERED(DID NOT CLICK REMEBER ME BUTTON) OR NO SESSION IS FOUND THEN THROW HIM OUT TO LOGIN
//SECURITY SO THAT USERS CANT ACCESS WEB URL DIRECTLY
 if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && !isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
 {
   header("Location: index.php");
 }
?>
```

The HeaderName directive works if I use regular php expressions like `echo` but does not work with the code above.

what am I doing wrong?

Help is appreciated

Comment: I'm willing to bet that headername is already outputting `<html><body>...` type stuff BEFORE it reaches the file you're including via headername, which means that `header()` calls are not permitted anymore.

Comment: But in php you can call html tag first then PHP, in PHP order is not an issue. But you might be right about the header() issue.

Comment: yeah, but you're not dealing with JUSt php... you're dealing with apache too, and unless apache calls your headre script BEFORE it does any other output, you'll never be able to get header() calls to work, because apache's already triggered output itself. you also couldn't use any PHP buffering methods, because PHP starts **AFTER** apache's done the output.

Comment: @MarcB As a work around I used meta tag refresh and it worked. However, even though the directory isn't accessible the files are. Anyway to prevent download of files unless logged in?

Comment: @fixnode don't allow direct access to the files that will download, use a script that starts the download, that way you can request login before the download starts